# OpenGL model with python and pygame

Tags: opengl, pygame, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a 3d model using pygame, OpenGL and numpy, while running this script I run into the following Errors

```
   Traceback (most recent call last:
    File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._finalCall(*args,**named)
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\Desktop\Python-graphic-game\3d-game\model.py", line 60, in <module>
   main()
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\Desktop\Python-graphic-game\3d-game\model.py", line 56, in main
m.draw()
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\Desktop\Python-graphic-game\3d-game\model.py", line 35, in draw
glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self._finalCall(*args,**named)
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\wrapper.py", line 675, in wrapper call
pyArgs = tuple(calculate_pyArgs(args))
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\wrapper.py", line 436, in calculate_pyArgs
yield converter(args[index], self, args)
File "C:\Users\[I]Username[/I]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\arrays\arrayhelpers.py", line 122, in asArraySize
incoming,
ValueError: ('Expected 12 byte array, got 8 byte array', (0,1), <function asArrayTypeSize.<locals>.asArraySize at 0x09212588>)
```

Here is the code in question:

```py
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import numpy

class threeDModel:
    nodes = [
        [0,0,0],
        [1.1,1.1,0],
        [0,-1.1,0],
        [0,-1.1,-1.1]
    ]
    vertices = [
        (0,1),
        (0,2),
        (0,3),
        (1,2),
        (1,3),
        (2,3)
    ]
    surfaces = (
        (0,1,2),
        (0,2,3)
    )
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = threeDModel.nodes
        self.vertices = threeDModel.vertices
        self.surfaces = threeDModel.surfaces
    def draw(self):
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        for surface in self.surfaces:
            for vertex in surface:
                glColor3f(1,0,0)
                glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()
```

So can anybody help me?

This is my first time using OpenGL, so please be nice to me.

I am also using the tutorials by Tech with Tim, that's why I'm using the from module import *, even though I know I'm not supposed to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code, it's impossible to help with all of it stripped out.

Comment: 2 things, 1 I asked if you could be nice, 2 I was doing this on phone, my tablet doesn't have internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertices` is an attribute of the class `threeDModel`. So it has to be **`self.vertices`**.

But content of the attribute `.vertices` is a list of pairs (tuples).

> ```
> vertices = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)]
> ```

Probably you want to draw `.nodes` rather than `.vertices`:

```py
class threeDModel:

    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        glColor3f(1,0,0)
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        for surface in self.surfaces:
            for i in surface:
                glVertex3fv(self.nodes[i])
        glEnd()
```

Or you want to draw the edges (wire frame):

```py
class threeDModel:

    # [...]
    def drawEdges(self):
        glColor3f(1,1,0)
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edges in self.vertices:
            for i in edges:
                glVertex3fv(self.nodes[i])
        glEnd()
```